# Extra spacing on eft col content when floating two divs side by side content

Tags: html, css

I am floating two divs side by side, my problem is the content on the left has a huge space on top. The height otherwise adjusts great. Is there any way to have the content horizontally aligned properly eliminating the huge space? Please see the link provided http://jsfiddle.net/darlene1624/zey0macx/.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="event">
            <img src="http://ima.gs/800x400.png" alt="event 1"  />
                </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
        <div class="eventdesc">
                            <div class="eventtitle">
                                <h2><a href="#">Carnival Party</a></h2>     
                             </div><p><strong>Where: </strong>TBA<br>
                            <strong>When: </strong>19/09/2014<br>
                            <strong>End Date: </strong>18/12/2014<br>
                            <strong>Time: </strong>7:00 pm<br>
                            <strong>Contact: </strong><br></p><br>

                            <div class="readmore">
                            <a href="#">Read More</a>
                            </div>

    </div>


.row {
    display: table;
}

.col {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 50%;

    padding: 1em;

 border-bottom: 1px solid #F5F8F9;
}

.event img{
width:100%;
 }

 .eventdesc{

    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;


 }

 .readmore {
 text-align:right;
 color: #FBE321;
 }


 .readmore a{

 color: #FBE321;
 }
```

Thanks,
D.

Comment: which huge space are you talking about ? can you specify which `div` you are concerned with ?

Comment: The class I am referring to is eventdesc, I would like both event and eventdec to be aligned horizontally where eventdesc aligns with the top of the image on class event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set:

```
.col {
    vertical-align: top;
}
h2 {
    margin-top: 0;
    line-height: 1em;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zey0macx/3/)